# python relativedelta get the wrong result

Tags: python, time, data-manipulation, relativedelta

The python function `relativedelta` calculates the time difference.
However, I get the wrong result.

```
from dateutil import relativedelta
y=relativedelta.relativedelta(pd.to_datetime('2006-01-11'), pd.to_datetime('1988-09-26')).years
m=relativedelta.relativedelta(pd.to_datetime('2006-01-11'), pd.to_datetime('1988-09-26')).months
y*12+m

207
# should be 208
```

But the above should be `208` since `m` should equal to `4` instead of `3`.

Another example gets the correct result:

```
y=relativedelta.relativedelta(pd.to_datetime('2006-01-11'), pd.to_datetime('2003-04-04')).years
m=relativedelta.relativedelta(pd.to_datetime('2006-01-11'), pd.to_datetime('2003-04-04')).months
y*12+m

33
# CORRECT!
```

```
y=relativedelta.relativedelta(pd.to_datetime('2006-01-17'), pd.to_datetime('2001-12-20')).years
m=relativedelta.relativedelta(pd.to_datetime('2006-01-17'), pd.to_datetime('2001-12-20')).months
y*12+m

48
# should be 49
```

Any idea?

Comment: The time difference for your first example is `relativedelta(years=+17, months=+3, days=+16)`. Why do you think it should be 208 and not 207?

Comment: I compare the result with SAS programming `INTCK('month', date1, date2)`.

Comment: From the documentation (which btw you should have gone through) of `INTCK`, default method of calculating difference is `Discrete`, which checks if 1st of a month is within the interval or not. This means `INTCK('month', '2020-01-31', '2020-02-01')` will return 1, while for `Continuous` method, `INTCK('month', '2020-01-31', '2020-02-01', 'C')` will return 0.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused... why the results are the same sometimes...?

Comment: The formula should be `month(date1)-month(date2)+12*(year(date1)-year(date2))`